# Specflow :Could not load file or assembly TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.2.0.0

Tags: specflow

I know this question is asked so many times but it is always difficult to updgrade Specflow from one version to another. Can anyone help in resolving below error while upgrading to 2.2.0.0 from 1.9.0 .

```
Could not load type 'TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.RuntimePluginAttribute' from assembly 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41'. Automation
```

I'v tried to follow this thread [Techtalk.Specflow error: Could not load assembly file or assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316353/techtalk-specflow-error-could-not-load-assembly-file-or-assembly) by putting Old version as "1.9.0.77"   and "1.9.0.0" but still no luck. Also tried to delete all packages from solution then from Temp folder and tried to load all . Also tried to uninstall Specflow .

Using VS 2015

can anyone help with it ?

Comment: Where do you get this error and which runtime plugins are you using?

Comment: its solved. what i found it Extensions for Specflow is getting disabled when we try to upgrade and that is the reason for getting this errors so once u get them enabled it will work .

Comment: Good to know that you get is solved. Please write an answer for this question so others find it quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Finally able to resolve the issue .

Solution is : Once you upgrade the Specflow to any versions , make sure Specflow for Visual studio Extension is Enabled. As in my case it was not Enabled (Got disabled in the process of Upgrade) and all errors were Occurring .