# Interface cannot be resolved error in Specflow

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I get this error when I run my `Specflow` test:

> Standard Output Messages:
> Given MRF "Bas.MarketFeed" application runs version "0.0.152"
> -> error: Interface cannot be resolved: Autofac.ILifetimeScope (resolution path: bas_test.Steps.BASIntegrationTestStepDefinitions) (0.5s)

I thought this was due to a missing `[Binding]` annotation but I have it on my class:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class BASIntegrationTestStepDefinitions
```

What could be causing this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316353/techtalk-specflow-error-could-not-load-assembly-file-or-assembly?force_isolation=true

Comment: Are your step definitions in a different assembly?